# how to fit a complex model to complex data

Tags: matlab, optimization, multidimensional-array, global, local

My aim is to fit gaussian-hermite-polynoms to complex measurement data (consisting out of absolute and an phase part). There are seven independent parameters (p) to generate such an gaussian-hermite-mode. I implement everthing in Matlab, so calculating such a mode is no problem. Problem is the fitting operation. At the moment, I implement two versions. First one is with `fminsearch`, the second one with `lsqnonlin`:

```
fun=@(p) CalcCoeff(c1,...
        p(1)*CalcGaussHermite(...
            CalcCoor([p(2),p(3),alphaZ],[p(4),p(5)],[centerX,centerY],labcoor),...
        [l,m,lambda,p(6),p(7)]));

p=[scale,alphaX,alphaY,z_fX,z_fY,w_0X,w_0Y];

%optimset('Display','iter','PlotFcns',@optimplotfval);
% [fpar,fval,exitflag,output] = fminsearch(fun,p,options);

options = optimoptions('lsqnonlin','Display','iter');
res=lsqnonlin(fun,p,[],[],options);
```

The function CalcCoeff calculates the difference in case of lsqnonlin, in case of fminsearch it calculates the overlap-integral (dot product).
As a test, I calculate a simple gaussian-mode and tried to reconstruct the parameters used. But my algorithm failed in both cases. It operates without any error message, but the parameters can't be reconstructed. So the question I ask myself is: are there too many parameters for the optimization, so the algorithm isn't able to converge? Or is it even a global problem?
I would be very pleased, if any optimization specialist would give me any hint what might go wrong.
If I asked my question in a wrong way just let me know.
Regards
Andre

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Thank for your help @Ander Biguri. Just one question: I have no idea why nobody is taking note of my question. Could you give my an advise? I edited the former stile, but it's still wrong? Is it not clear or precise enough? I would like to discuss my point, but it’s hard if nobody else wants to.
Best regards 
Andre

Comment: It looks way better now, this were good edits. However, you are asking us to have a look at some non-trivial maths and code, however you haven't provided a [mcve] for us to try, so we can at best guess. On top of that, the question is slightly more mathy than its cody, and this is a programming website. That also helps not getting much attention. I am a semi-expert in optiimzation, and I do not understand the question, so consider adding a MCVE as I said before, and explaining better what exatcly are you modeling, otherwise we wont know e.g. if there are too many parameters,